# BloC State Management

Tags: flutter, bloc, state-management

I need help from the community with the following question:

I have a flutter web application that displays a menu when hovering over a specific text. When this menu opens I can click on the desired item and I am redirected to another specific screen.
I created the - very simple - code below to exemplify the behavior I described above.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main(){
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      home: Example(),
    )
  );
}

class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  const Example({super.key});

  @override
  State<Example> createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {

  final PageController _pageController = PageController();

  static const Map<String, String> _optionsConsult = {
    'test' : 'test',
  };

  void _showPopupConsult(BuildContext context) async {
    //*get the render box from the context
    final RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    //*get the global position, from the widget local position
    final offset = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
    //*calculate the start point in this case, below the button
    final left = offset.dx + renderBox.size.width;
    final top = offset.dy;
    //*The right does not indicates the width
    final right = left + renderBox.size.width;
    //*show the menu
    await showMenu<String>(
        color: Colors.orange,
        context: context,
        position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(left, top, right, 0.0),
        items: _optionsConsult.entries.map<PopupMenuEntry<String>>((entry) {
          return PopupMenuItem(
            onTap: (){
              if(entry.key == 'test'){
                //GO TO OTHER PAGE
              }
            },
            value: entry.key,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                const SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                Text(
                  entry.key,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 12
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        }).toList()
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          MouseRegion(
              onEnter: (_) => _showPopupConsult(context),
              child: const Center(child: Text('Example'))
          )
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```

I'm studying the BloC State Management and I'm not able to implement this functionality using it. Can anyone help me rewriting the given example but using BloC to manage the state?